# Rename Mediawiki Special Page tab only for specific Special Pages

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I have several special pages I've created for an extension and would like the tab at the top of the page to show a custom label instead of "Special page".

I don't want to change the labels of all special pages, just specific special pages.

Is there a function from the SpecialPage class that will do that?

Or is there another route I should be looking at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [SkinTemplateNavigation::SpecialPage](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Hooks/SkinTemplateNavigation::SpecialPage). See how CentralNotice [uses it](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-CentralNotice/blob/f8d45a66c50d4f7a0c9ce5af218248d73187a1c8/special/SpecialCentralNotice.php#L1549-L1581) for example (it will look [like this](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:CentralNotice)).

Comment: Thanks, Tgr!  I haven't tried it yet, but clearly it's the correct way.

It'll be my Saturday morning project with my coffee!

Comment: I got it working.  I added the hook and set the pages in the extension.json file, and then made a few changes to the addNavigationTabs function since I only wanted to change the name of that one specific tab and not add others, but everything works great.  Appreciate the point in the right direction!